# create_taskについて

Tags: c++

pplx::create_taskでtask作成しています。
データをstd::forwardで渡しているのに、コピーコンストラクタが実行されてしまいます。
ここは通常のラムダ式であれば、ムーブコンストラクタが実行されるのですが、
コピーコンストラクタではなく、ムーブコンストラクタが動作してほしいのですが、何か方法があるでしょうか？
create_task内のラムダ式だとコピーコンストラクターが実行されるようです。

```
#include "cpprest/http_client.h"
#include "cpprest/filestream.h"

struct Test
{
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;  // データ
  int value;

  Test(std::unique_ptr<int[]>&& d)
    : data(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<int[]>>(d))
  {
  }

  Test(const Test& _obj)
  {
    ::OutputDebugStringW(L"copy\n");
  }

  Test(Test&& _obj) noexcept
    : data(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<int[]>>(_obj.data))
  {
    ::OutputDebugStringW(L"move\n");
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> data = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
  Test sample(std::move(data));
  std::vector<Test> List;
  List.emplace_back(std::move(sample));
  
  pplx::create_task([
     test_c = std::forward<std::vector<Test>>(List),
   ]()
  { 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pplx::create_task()`](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/v2.10.18/Release/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h#L4873-L4888)ですが、

```
__declspec(noinline) auto create_task(_Ty _Param, task_options _TaskOptions = task_options())
    -> task<typename details::_TaskTypeFromParam<_Ty>::_Type>
{
    ...
    task<typename details::_TaskTypeFromParam<_Ty>::_Type> _CreatedTask(_Param, _TaskOptions);
    return _CreatedTask;
}
```

となっているので、ラムダ式へはムーブされていますが、肝心のラムダ式 `_Param` がコピーされてるようです。
別質問でもいろいろとされているようですが、素直に参照渡しすべきかと。
参照渡ししていれば、ラムダ式がコピーされても参照がコピーされるだけとなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。taskは非同期で動作するため、dataは、task外では消えるため、参照が使用できず、あまりコピーを発生させずに、完全移行させたかったのですが、残念ながら、コピーされてしまうようで。別の方法がないか考えてみます。

Comment: @kk Q&Aサイトとは、質問者さんの心の内に秘める期待に応えるものではなく、（質問者さんと切り離して）あくまで記述された質問文に答えるものであることを理解してください。本当に答えて欲しい内容が質問文として記述されないと、回答者としても心苦しいだけです。コメントを読む限り本当に尋ねたかったのは「pplx::create_task()に渡すラムダ式でコピーが発生しないようにしたい」とかその辺りなのではと想像しています。必要であれば別スレッドで質問しなおしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その通りです。その時々の対応を模索していたのですが、
もっと最終的な問題の質問にすべきでした。